# I want to make image slides in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to make image slides in my Flutter app.

Once the first image is loaded i need to start a timer and after 3 minutes i want to show the second image.

[**Add 3 minute timer on image after timer end next image will show **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvObI.jpg)

Comment: Check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your current question is unlikely to receive answers.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider . Try this package